# How to distribute table rows (from second to last) in PowerPoint with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to distribute evenly rows across a presentation, so that from the second to the last of each slide they fit into the drawing area (that is, they reach the bottom of the content placeholder of the layout "Title and Content"
`Set masterShape = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2).Shapes.Placeholders(2)`), while the first row should always be of the same height. However, I can only achieve this last point (the heading is indeed of the same height), while in each slide the total height is smaller than that of the reference placeholder. Below the code I have written.

```
Sub AdjustTableHeight()
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oSld As slide
Dim p As Integer

Dim masterShape As Shape


Set masterShape = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2).Shapes.Placeholders(2)


        For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes


             If oShp.HasTable = msoTrue Then

                With ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
                    firstRowHeight = oShp.Table.Rows(1).Height
                End With
             
             
                oShp.Left = masterShape.Left
                oShp.Top = masterShape.Top
                oShp.Width = masterShape.Width

             
                With oShp.Table.Rows(1)
                    .Height = firstRowHeight
                End With
             
                For p = 2 To oShp.Table.Rows.Count 

                      oShp.Table.Rows(p).Height = (masterShape.Height - firstRowHeight) / oShp.Table.Rows.Count - 1 ' I also tried dividing by p, but the rows become very high and not equal to each other
    
                Next p

             End If

            Next oShp
        Next oSld


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses around oShp.Table.Rows.Count - 1 to ensure subtraction happens before the division. Here's your macro in a more succinct form:

```
Sub AdjustTableHeight()
    Dim oShp As Shape, masterShape As Shape
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim p As Integer
    
    Set masterShape = ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2).Shapes.Placeholders(2)
    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
            If oShp.HasTable = msoTrue Then
                With oShp
                    firstRowHeight = .Table.Rows(1).Height
                    .Left = masterShape.Left
                    .Top = masterShape.Top
                    .Width = masterShape.Width
                    .Table.Rows(1).Height = firstRowHeight
                    For p = 2 To .Table.Rows.Count
                        .Table.Rows(p).Height = (masterShape.Height - firstRowHeight) / (.Table.Rows.Count - 1)
                    Next p
                End With
            End If
        Next oShp
    Next oSld
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I had been wondering for hours why it was not working, the logic overall seemed correct to me. One question: why if I divide by `p` the height changes across rows, should it not be the same as dividing by the number of rows minus one (the heading)?

Comment: I think I can answer my own question to you: I would say that by dividing by `p` each row is divided by the remainder of `p` at each loop, that is why they get increasingly smaller. In that case, would there be a way to point to the `p` number of total rows?

Comment: You're right about using the value of p. You could create a separate variable that you set to the number of rows minus the first, but this solution works just as well.

Comment: I understand, so for example I could put some `q = g` at the beginning of the loop and refer to that variable instead of `p`. I am absolutely fine with the solution you gave, I was just wondering on how to "fixate" the variable in some ways. Thank you.